# SQL Server DBCC CLONEDATABASE WITH VERIFY_CLONEDB and the database is still read-only?

Tags: sql-server

I tried to use the `CLONEDATABASE WITH VERIFY_CLONEDB`. It does what I want, except that the CLONE is read-only. What is the point of `WITH VERIFY_CLONEDB` then?

I thought this will make a 100% clone of my selected database which will be ready for production and than this new cloned database can be used for "testing/inserting/updating/deleting". If this is not the way of making a "copy" of a database, can someone please tell me how to make a copy of a database "programmatically", not by hand doing a backup and than restoring that backup into a new database ...

If this won't work, I will simply use `sqlcmd` to create a backup and `sqlcmd` to import that backup into a new database.

Comment: `CLONEDATABASE` is for creating a schema-only duplicate, by default including histogram statistics, for troubleshooting purposes. `CLONEDATABASE` does *not* copy data, so it's unlikely this is what you want to begin with. If it is, a simple `ALTER DATABASE [MyClone] SET READ_WRITE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` will make your clone writable. If you want a copy of all data, well, that's *exactly* what `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` are for; both statements are scriptable, so this needs to be no more "by hand" than cloning the database.

Comment: For a development pipeline where you want to roll out databases from test to production, neither approach is very suitable; consider using things like [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/sql-server-data-tools) and `sqlpackage` (DACPACs and BACPACs).

Comment: Which parameter do i have to use in order to restore the database into a new one? Lets say i have a database with name "test", i do a `sqlcmd backup to disk` in order to get a .bak file. Now i want to restore it into a new database called "test_2022". Using `sqlcmd restore database test_2022 from disk` tries to restore to the already existing database "test".

Comment: This exact scenario is described [with an example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql#copying_db_using_bnr). You'll need to use the `MOVE` option to give the existing files new locations.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now that i have to specified the data and log files with the path ... Is there a way to use the "default" path specified in the SQL server? Or will i have to specify the path always with the files?

Comment: There is no option in `RESTORE` to use that path. You can cobble something together programmatically using `SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath')` and `SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath')`, but since `RESTORE` doesn't accept variables you'd have to construct the statement dynamically.